# (Scheme) eq? eqv? equal? Difference

Tags: lisp, scheme, equality

I really cant figure out the major difference between `eq?`, `eqv?` and `equal?`

Please explain this.

Besides, why do we need them?

Comment: Use eq? For symbols and to identify same object, equal? for stuff that look the same. (Land of LISP)

Comment: of the two answers on the duplicate, one is nothing but a link - to the whole-document PDF at that, not even to a specific section - and the other is not much more than a link either - it does mention "value equivalence" and "same object" but does not explain what these terms mean. So the question is left unanswered in the "duplicate" IMHO. Vote to reopen.

Comment: @WillNess The answers to this question are similar, so nothing is gained by keeping both versions.  Maybe merge them and/or place a bounty on the original?

Comment: @finnw whatever you feel is right. :) I'm not good with this meta stuff. :) Merging seems right, how do we do that?

Answer (score 4):

For a technical explanation, take a look at the [specification](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.5), you won't find a more detailed reference. Or simply check your interpreter's [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html), for example in Racket:

**`(equal? v1 v2) → boolean?`**

> Two values are `equal?` if and only if they are `eqv?`, unless otherwise specified for a particular datatype. Datatypes with further specification of `equal?` include strings, byte strings, pairs, mutable pairs, vectors, boxes, hash tables, and inspectable structures. In the last six cases, equality is recursively defined; if both `v1` and `v2` contain reference cycles, they are equal when the infinite unfoldings of the values would be equal.

**`(eqv? v1 v2) → boolean?`**

> Two values are `eqv?` if and only if they are `eq?`, unless otherwise specified for a particular datatype. The number and character datatypes are the only ones for which `eqv?` differs from `eq?`.

**`(eq? v1 v2) → boolean?`**

> `eq?` returns `#t` if `v1` and `v2` refer to the same object, `#f` otherwise.  See also [Object Identity and Comparisons](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._model-eq%29).

Answer (score 1):

There are a full two pages in the RNRS specification related to `eq?, eqv?, equal? and =`.  Here is the [Draft R7RS Specification](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/r7rs-draft-8.pdf).  Check it out!